# Moving from fragment to fragment managed by Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I took Navigation Drawer from Android Studio template. Everything works fine, but there are several problems associated with not understanding this component. I'm almost new, came from Delphi.

I need to come up with a transition between fragments from the Navigation Drawer, in the fragment itself, by pressing a button. That is, fragment1: buttonclick> fragment2.The usual Intent does not work, and the FragmentManager, as I understand it, only changes the xml files, and I need to initialize the class. All rummaged, found nothing like that.

MainActivity:

```
package esport.inyourlife.insport;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import esport.inyourlife.insport.ui.slideshow.ProfileFragment;

public class HomeNav extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private TextView uMail, uName;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_nav);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(view -> Snackbar.make(view, "Позже уберу эту штуку, при оптимизаций приложений", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show());
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_tournament, R.id.nav_profile)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        uMail = findViewById(R.id.uMail);
        uName = findViewById(R.id.uName);
        /*Intent i = getIntent();
        if (i != null)
        {
            uMail.setText(i.getStringExtra("email"));
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка получения емайл", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/
        /*
        FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener stateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (user != null)
                {
                    mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(this);
                    uMail.setText(user.getEmail());
                    if (!user.getDisplayName().equals(null))
                    {
                        uName.setText(user.getDisplayName());
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(stateListener);*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_nav, menu);
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.signout :
            mAuth.signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoadFrame.class));
            finish();
            return true;
            case R.id.test :
                Toast.makeText(this, "Отсутсвует метод", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
    public void Profile(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileFragment.class));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    // public void SignOut(View view) { mAuth.signOut(); }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To navigate from current fragment to next fragment, use this code in your current fragment:

```
Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.xml_button);
button.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.nextFragment, null));
```

To navigate with a transition animation, set the id of the fragment you want to navigate to (nextFragment), to the id of the action containing the fragment transition.

```
Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.xml_button);
button.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_currentFragment_to_nextFragment, null));
```

If you already have an onClickListener set for the button, place this inside it instead:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.nextFragment);
```

Comment: ooh, everything turned out to be much easier ?! Thank you Andrew, you are my hero savior. by the way are you russian? so by the way, since you're Andrey ..
Of course, I began to complicate the task for myself and tried to get navhost through MainActivity without even reading the message, and for several days I swore at the authors of the template)) Damn, thanks a lot Andrew

Comment: unfortunately there is no reputation to put a plus sign or somehow to thank you, you have no idea how I was tormented with this navigation